# How do I delete isolates in my network in R?

Tags: r, networking

I have a matrix ("g") and I'm trying to remove isolates (unconnected nodes). I tried using delete_isolates(g) in the hierformR package, and I tried using in the corpustools package.

Both times I got an error: 
Error in delete_isolates(g) : could not find function "delete_isolates"

How do I remove unconnected nodes from my matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to include a minimal reproducible example of your data. Check [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

With the `igraph` package you and following example matrix `g`

```
library(igraph)
g <-structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    NULL))
```

transform your matrix into a graph object

```
g.old <- graph.adjacency(g, mode = "undirected", diag = FALSE)
```

and delete nodes with a degree of 0

```
g.new <- delete.vertices(g.old , which(degree(g.old)==0))
```